# What should you do if you discover that the assumption underlying your question is incorrect?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, asking-questions

Say, for instance, that you asked why was P the case, P being a statement. But after doing further research you discover that P is not in fact the case. What would be the appropriate course of action then?

Should you delete the question, add an update to explain your findings, or do something different?

Comment: Ideally you should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for P when you initially ask the question. This would prevent such situations from happening. In that case even if it turns out that P is a misunderstanding people can provide an answer to clarify that. Can you expand more on the particular case you are talking about?

Comment: Add an answer explaining that P is not the case.

Comment: This sounds like the question is no longer reproducible, which would normally mean the question should be closed. If you're received answers, or one and it has an upvote, you won't be able to delete your question though. In truth, however, this is an example of why we ask that you do the research first before posting, and doing things like trying to create an MRE, as doing so will likely expose such matters.

Comment: @ThomA but in the case that you misinterpret the MRE? Let's assume the OP did their research, but just completely misunderstands P

Comment: That could be an example for a good answer explaining, @Cerbrus . I, will admit, I assumed otherwise as the OP states *"after doing further research"* which could imply enough wasn't done to start with.

Comment: @ThomA You can continue researching after asking. Discovering that your question was based on a false assumption does not mean that you did no research before asking. As for the MRE, I don't think that what you're saying is always applicable, though I can see cases where it does apply.

Comment: The question you describe is very vague, so we can't tell from that if an MRE would be applicable or not, @MehdiCharife .

Comment: @ThomA, now I'm nitpicking, but _"further"_ implies research was done beforehand :D

Comment: Which is why stated "enough wasn't done". "Not enough" doesn't mean none, @Cerbrus . I never said the OP didn't research prior to posting their question.

Comment: What is "enough"... If you have a sudden insight 1 day after posting a question, wasn't the research enough? What about 2 days? A week? My point is that the reseach beforehand really doesn't matter. OP is asking what to do if he realizes he'd had some misconceptions.

Comment: I think you're incorrectly "nitpicking" my statements to play devil's advocate at this point.

Comment: No, I'm just stating "Do your research first" is not an answer to this question.

Comment: If the question is not yet answered, and the misunderstanding you had does not seem as valuable and helpful to others that may have similar misunderstanding, then the best would be to delete the question. If  you feel that misunderstanding is common enough, then you can add answer explaining it. If there are answers then there is very little you can do and  you should not edit the question in a way that would invalidate answers.

Comment: *"No, I'm just stating "Do your research first" is not an answer to this question."* I'm glad you agree with me now then, I never said that either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To summarize the comments and my understanding of the [SO help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking):

Ask yourself:

- Was this caused by a typo, non-reproducible error (E.g. forgot to save the file before compiling/running), [lack of a reasonable research effort](https://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error)? -> Remove/Close the question
- Was it caused by a misconception that could be easily made by anyone, aka. others might run into the same issue and benefit from your Q&A (E.g. until version x.y.z P behaves as such, in version x.y.zz it does not)? -> Add an answer clarifying (& improve the question if needed)

Comment: "Add an answer clarifying (& improve the question if needed)" - in particular, consider adding verbiage like "appears to" to the title.